Entries in center but right-aligned in tabularray
Can we have entries right-aligned but in center in tabularray? Here is the picture that I want:

Please edit your query to show the code that gives rise to the screenshot you posted. That way, we won't have to hand-enter the information.

Guess: Have a look at siunitx library in the tabularray documentation.

The screenshot is from a published book. I want to create such a table in tabularray.

Welcome! What have you tried so far?

I can align in center or left or right. But I want column entries in center but right-aligned.

You don't want the numbers to be purely right-aligned. Instead, you want them aligned on their (here implicit) decimal markers.

Employing the tabularray package and its tblr environment seems like incurring way too much overhead for the simple table that needs to be generated. I'd use a basic array environment instead.
To achieve your formatting objective, I suggest you load the siunitx package and employ its S column type to align the numbers on their (here implicit) decimal markers.
I'd also do away with the vertical rules, which aren't needed.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{booktabs}   % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros
\usepackage{siunitx}    % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for \lvert and \rvert macros
\usepackage{newtx}      % optional (Times Roman text and math fonts)
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{}
              S[table-format=2.0]  % 2 integer digits, 0 decimal digits
              S[table-format=-2.0] % ditto & set aside space for '-' symbol
              S[table-format=2.0] 
              @{}}
\toprule
{x_i} & {x_i-\bar{x}} & {\lvert x_i-\bar{x} \rvert} \\ 
      % simple centering of contents of header cells
\midrule
10 & -15 & 15 \\
20 &  -5 &  5 \\
30 &   5 &  5 \\
40 &  15 & 15 \\
\midrule
{\Sigma \colon 100} \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}


Thanks @Mico. Using siunitx creates the table. I had to use "row{1} = {guard}" for the first row.
